# Trigger a file in SSH (Paramiko) in python

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, triggers, paramiko

I want to trigger a file(which,takes a lot of time to execute) by accessing a remote desktop using paramiko module. But by using

`stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command("any command which takes up a long time to execute")`

python interpreter waits until the file stopped running. But I don't want that I just want it to trigger the file and move to the next line in the code. How should I do that? Any help will be very much appreciated,thanks

Comment: Google "python asynchronous"